# Getting a Spring Exception when not using Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am encountering a problem getting CDI to work with a JAX-WS web service implementation.  While trying to debug this problem, however, I am seeing an exception in the logs that I am having trouble understanding.  The log, and the exception is (5th line down starting with '[WARNING]':

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.6/wlp-1.0.9.cl50620150610-1749) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_79-b15 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.6/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the path.not.important.external.service.eNC3BusinessWebServiceImpl class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9090/eNC3BusinessWebService/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application eNC3BusinessWebService_EAR started in 2.841 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jaxws-2.2, cdi-1.2, servlet-3.1, jndi-1.0, javaMail-1.5, jaxb-2.2].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

I am confused as to why any spring classes would be loaded.  I am not using Spring at all.  This is a pure Java 7 implementation of a JAX-WS webservice.  The following is my implementation class:

```
package path.not.important.external.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import path.not.important.external.domain.DemographicBean;
import path.not.important.external.domain.ErrorInfo;
import path.not.important.external.domain.SubmissionValidationResults;
import path.not.important.internal.client.FileSubmissionServiceHandler;
import path.not.important.rules.submission.BRSubmissionService;
import path.not.important.internal.SubmissionFormData;
import path.not.important.plugin.IResult;
import path.not.important.plugin.SubmissionResult;

@WebService(serviceName="eNC3BusinessWebService")
public class eNC3BusinessWebServiceImpl
{

    @WebMethod
    public SubmissionValidationResults xmlValidation(String xml, String submissionType, String schemaVersion)
            throws SOAPException
    {
        logger.info("--- Validating Incomming Form XML ---");

        logger.info("Received Payload: XML [" + xml + "]");
        logger.info("SubmissionType [" + submissionType + "]");
        logger.info("SchemaVersion [" + schemaVersion + "]");

        return results;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public SubmissionValidationResults flatFileValidation(String filename, byte[] file) throws SOAPException
    {
        logger.info("--- Converting and Validating Incomming Form Flat File ---");

        logger.info("Validating flat file: " + filename);
        logger.info("file size: " + file.length);
        logger.info("file: " + file.toString());

        return results;
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String finalNC3FormSubmission(DemographicBean demographicData, List<SubmissionFormData> nc3,
            List<SubmissionFormData> irsW2, List<SubmissionFormData> irs1099) throws SOAPException
    {
        logger.info("Executing final submission of website form data...");

        return messageID;
    }

    @Inject
    private FileSubmissionServiceHandler fileSubmissionServiceHandler;

    @Inject
    private BRSubmissionService brSubmissionService;

    public static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(eNC3BusinessWebServiceImpl.class);
}
```

I do not know if my CDI problem and this issue are related, but I am trying to eliminate any other cause of the problem.  My CDI issue is documented here:
[JAX-WS and CDI not working together on WAS Liberty Profile 8.5.5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074041/jax-ws-and-cdi-not-working-together-on-was-liberty-profile-8-5-5-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally isolated the cause of the problem.  This answers my other question as well.

The object called BRSubmissionService is being loaded by CDI.  CDI loading is being interrupted by the spring exception.  And because CDI is not able to complete, the remaining CDI injections do not occur and my FileSubmissionService object is not loaded, causing my null pointer exception.

The solution is to fix the spring error inside the BRSubmissionService object which is located in another jar, that unfortunately I've inherited from another developer.  Such is the life.